# How to parse .kar files in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi

I need to parse a .KAR file to read your lyrics and print in the screen, how I parse a .kar file using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Karapython](https://github.com/hsocasnavarro/Karapython) may do what you need.

If you're looking to roll your own solution, you may need to learn how to use Python's [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library.

Comment: Karapython is for python2, have another module that runs in python3?